# Gausian Filter with OpenCV and C++

Tags: c++, opencv

My goal is to apply a gaussian filter to an input image.
I don't want to use the OpenCV function (i want to program it by myself).
I mention the Error in the code. Can somebody help me? The code is based on a mean filter example. 
I know the examples with the GaussianBlur function.

```
  public:Mat gaussianfilter(const Mat input, int n, float sigmaT, float sigmaS, const char* opt) {

            Mat kernel;

            int row = input.rows;
            int col = input.cols;
            int kernel_size = (2 * n + 1);
            int tempa;
            int tempb;
            float denom;
            float kernelvalue{};

            // Initialiazing Kernel Matrix 
            kernel = Mat::zeros(kernel_size, kernel_size, CV_32F);


            denom = 0.0;
            for (int a = -n; a <= n; a++) {  // Denominator in m(s,t)
                for (int b = -n; b <= n; b++) {
                    float value1 = exp(-(pow(a, 2) / (2 * pow(sigmaS, 2))) - (pow(b, 2) / (2 * pow(sigmaT, 2))));
                    kernel.at<float>(a + n, b + n) = value1;
                    denom += value1;
                }
            }

            for (int a = -n; a <= n; a++) {  // Denominator in m(s,t)
                for (int b = -n; b <= n; b++) {
                    kernel.at<float>(a + n, b + n) /= denom;
                }
            }

            Mat output = Mat::zeros(row, col, input.type());


            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {



                        float sum1 = 0.0;
                        for (int a = -n; a <= n; a++) {
                            for (int b = -n; b <= n; b++) {

                                /* Gaussian filter with Zero-paddle boundary process:

                                Fill the code:
                                */

                                if ((i + a <= row - 1) && (i + a >= 0) && (j + b <= col - 1) && (j + b >= 0)) { //if the pixel is not a border pixel
 /*here is a failure: Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "+=" */

                                    sum1 += kernel * (float)(input.at<G>(i + a, j + b));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        output.at<G>(i, j) = (G)sum1;
                    }






            }
            return output;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

sum1 - float , kernel - Mat. You can't += for float and Mat. You need to append indices.

```
sum1 += kernel.at<float>(a+n,b+n) * (float)(input.at<G>(i + a, j + b));
```

I think.